Ошибка 404 при запуске коллекции
Почему постман может выдавать ошибку 404 при run collection? Когда запускаю отдельно статус код 200, при запуске коллекции put и delete выдает 404. С чем может быть связано? Как исправить

Эти URL-адреса не существует для этих запросов.

Чтобы дополнить свой вопрос, совсем не обязательно его задавать заново в немного изменённом виде: для этого есть кнопка "править" под текстом вопроса. Оставьте этот вопрос, а прошлый удалите.
